# Using regex to catch all matches with specific rule from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string:

```
var x = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="{url}">This is an example of url with the URL keyword</a>
        <p>This is another keyword: {link1}</p>
    </body>
</html>'
```

I want to make a array with all **{chr}** matches. A rule like this:

*Each word with 10 characters max length wrapped by { and } in **x**, add in array*

I think this can be done using regex but i'm new to regex and don't know how to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
var arr = x.match(/{\w{1,10}}/g);
// ["{url}", "{link1}"]
```

Comment: Aren't `{` and `}` special chars in a regex?

Comment: @Ian They are, but not in this case.

Comment: Interesting. Does it work because there's no preceding character?

Comment: @Ian I guess so. Since there is no preceding character JS treat it as is.

Comment: this is unfair I answered first and have way less rep, what gives?

Comment: your answer wasn't complete - missing the 'g' for global. but this answer has an extra '?' quantifier for some reason. what's that about?

Comment: @BrianStephens This qualifier is required to make a non-greedy matching (just in case `\w` is replaced with `.*`). You may read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark). **BTW**, I was the second to answer this question after the removed #adeneo's answer. This could be easily checked if you hover the time of the answer.

Comment: I know about lazy quantifiers. It's extraneous in this situation, though. Nothing in `\w` could match the following curly bracket, so the default greedy is OK. I agree that if it's replaced with `.*` it would be needed, but your answer is half one, half the other.

Comment: @BrianStephens Agree. I have removed the confusing syntax. Now the solution should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var results = x.match(/\{\w{1,10}\}/g)
```

tell me if it works

Comment: Youre missing the `g`, hence this will return only the first match, OP wanted them all...

Comment: thanks, I gues that's inexperience showing, I've never had to use the 'g'